# how to identify a lang attribute on a HTML in vue file without using vue-i18n

Tags: attributes, vuejs3, lang

i'm new to vue and i got this task to solve.

1.- I display some dummy data from index.html on my App.vue file

2.- The next step is to identify the language of the index.html without using vue-i18n

3.- My qustion is how do i get the attribute from index.html so that the laguage can be identify in   App.vue file. I have search a lot of documention, men everything points to vue-i18n, and that's what it can't be used to solve this problem. Can someone explain it to me please?

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
**<html lang="en">** // This is what i to need to get 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
      const dummyData = {
        name: "Peter",
        age: 37
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my App.vue file

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const person = computed(() => {
    return dummyData.name
})
const years = ref(dummyData.age)
</script>
    
<template>
    <div class="m-0 row vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center "> 
        <div class="col-auto bg-primary p-5 text-center text-white rounded-3 ">
            <p>{{ person }} it's my name</p>
            <p>I'm {{ years }} years old</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried a simple query selector already?

```
function getLang () {
    return document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang')
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really worked. The only change i made was "const" instead of function. Thank you.